# Traverse thorough Nested JSON Object and add attribute

Tags: javascript, json, angular

I have a JSON input which can go to any number of levels.
I want to add the one attribute in all levels

```
[{
  title:' ' ,
  id : ' ',
  description: ' ',
  date :' ',
  children:[{
     children : [{ 
     ....
      }]
    title:' ' ,
    id : ' ',
    description: ' ',
    date :' ',  
   }]
  },
  title:' ' ,
  id : ' ',
  description: ' ',
  date :' ',
  children:[{
    children : [{ 
     ....
    }]
   ...
    }]
  }]
```

I want to add an isShow attribute at each level.
How do I get into the inner levels for JSON?

Comment: Please post  your code, or what you have tried

Comment: @Joel Joseph sorry my bad

Comment: That isn't JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add an `isShown` property to each item and to each of its children recursively, here is a way to do it.

This solution uses [`Array.isArray(x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) to check if `x` is an array and [`x instanceof Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) to check if `x` is an object. If `x` is an array [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) is used to apply the function to each entry, if `x` is an object, the property is added and `forEach` is used to apply the function to each child.

```js
const data = [{
  title: '',
  id: '',
  description: '',
  date: '',
  children: [{
    children: [{}],
    title: '',
    id: '',
    description: '',
    date: '',  
  }]
}, {
  title: '',
  id: '',
  description: '',
  date: '',
  children: [{ children: [{}] }]
}];

function addIsShown(x) {
  if (Array.isArray(x)) { // if data is an array
    x.forEach(addIsShown); // call the function on each item
  } else if (x instanceof Object) { // otherwise, if data is an object
    x.isShown = true; // add prop to object
    (x.children || []).forEach(addIsShown); // and call function on each child
  }
}

addIsShown(data);

console.log(data)
```

Comment: @jo_vaI  tried u r solution .. giving error core.js:14597 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'addIsShown' of undefined . Can you ellobrate it in angular way?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a job for a reviver function...

```js
// https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/08/08/fixing-the-javascript-typeof-operator/
nTypeof = function (obj) {
  return ({}).toString.call(obj).match(/\s([a-z|A-Z]+)/)[1].toLowerCase();
};
var input = `[{
  "title":" " ,
  "id" : " ",
  "description": " ",
  "date" :" ",
  "children":[{
  "title":" " ,
  "id" : " ",
  "description": " ",
  "date" :" "
  }]
  }]`
  var output = JSON.parse(input,
    // reviver function called for each node in the JSON
    (key,value)=>{
      if(nTypeof(value) === "object")
        value.isShown = 0
      return value
    })
  console.log(output)
```